# Adding metamask extension using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to add a metamask extension using `selenium`, I know how to add an extension using selenium but whenever I try to add metamask extension it shows me the following error:

> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: failed to wait for extension background page to load: chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/background.html
> from timeout: Timed out receiving a message from renderer: 10.000

This is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
option = Options()
option.add_extension('metamask.crx')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the .crx in the directory of your project or specify its path: https://dev.to/ltmenezes/automated-dapps-scrapping-with-selenium-and-metamask-2ae9

Then you didn't initialize url.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).